# how to display same polygon on 2 maps present in different divs in the same page

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google maps api V3.
I have a polygonpoints array as like in this [Link's](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple) variable 'triangleCoords'.

I am generating maps dynamically using a button click..

I want to place the same polygon to be included in all maps.

As i am trying, the Polygon only displayed on the latest Map that is generated.

I want the Polygons to be like as in the [Image Link](http://i1324.photobucket.com/albums/u616/7842587827/Track_zps4f54b610.png?t=1363753715)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add a google.maps.Polygon to one map.  If you have multiple maps, you need to make one for each.

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var bermudaTriangle;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'),
        mapOptions);
    var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas3'),
        mapOptions);


    var triangleCoords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
        new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
        new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
        new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
    ];

    // Construct the polygon
    var bermudaTriangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: triangleCoords,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    var bermudaTriangle2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
      map: map2,
      paths: triangleCoords,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    var bermudaTriangle3 = new google.maps.Polygon({
      map: map3,
      paths: triangleCoords,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    bermudaTriangle1.setMap(map);
  }
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polygon-simple_3maps.html)